# How to convert a ruby struct of Aws::EC2::Types::Tag to a normal ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

Anyone could you please help me on how to get value for the key 'stack' from below ruby struct. This struct has returned when i fetched details of an instance and did

instance.tags 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
The data was something like this.

<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Env", value="Dev">
<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="role", value="test-app">
<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="stack", value="next">

This is the array of ruby structure of Aws::EC2::Types::Tag type.
```

I had these data in a variable i.e. tags. I am fetching tags details of an existing AWS instance. I am using ruby AWS SDK version 3. So what i did to get the key and value from the respective data.

```
@@instance = Aws::EC2::Instance.new(instance_id)
@@tags = instance.tags
tags.each do |tg|
      temp_tg=tg.to_h
      if temp_tg[:key] == "stack"
           stack = temp_tg[:value]
           #puts stack
      end
      if temp_tg[:key] == "role"
           role = temp_tg[:value]
           #puts role
      end
      if temp_tg[:key] == "Env"
           Env = temp_tg[:value]
           #puts Env
      end
end
```

It worked for me. There may be some other great ways to achieve this.
I'll appreciate if anyone gives a better version or approach of this. Thanks in advance.